# Which is the best .Net XML-RPC library?

Tags: .net, xml-rpc

I need to communicate with an XML-RPC server from a .NET 2.0 client. Can you recommend any libraries?

EDIT: Having tried XML-RPC.Net, I like the way it generates dynamic proxies, it is very neat. Unfortunately, as always, things are not so simple. I am accessing an XML-RPC service which uses the unorthodox technique of having object names in the names of the methods, like so:

```
object1.object2.someMethod(string1)
```

This means I can't use the attributes to set the names of my methods, as they are not known until run-time. If you start trying to get closer to the raw calls, XML-RPC.Net starts to get pretty messy.

So, anyone know of a simple and straightforward XML-RPC library that'll just let me do (pseudocode):

```
x = new xmlrpc(host, port)
x.makeCall("methodName", "arg1");
```

I had a look at a thing by Michael somebody on Codeproject, but there are no unit tests and the code looks pretty dire.

Unless someone has a better idea looks like I am going to have to start an open source project myself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method name is all that is changing (i.e., the method signature is static) XML-RPC.NET can handle this for you.  This is addressed [in the FAQ](http://xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq.html#2.23), noting "However, there are some XML-RPC APIs which require the method name to be generated dynamically at runtime..."  From the FAQ:

```
ISumAndDiff proxy = (ISumAndDiff)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(ISumAndDiff));
proxy.XmlRpcMethod = "Id1234_SumAndDifference"
proxy.SumAndDifference(3, 4);
```

This generates an XmlRpcProxy which implementes the specified interface.  Setting the XmlRpcMethod attribute causes methodCalls to use the new method name.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the library from [www.xml-rpc.net](http://www.xml-rpc.net/) some time ago with some success and can recommend it -- it did feel well designed and functional.

Answer (score 1):

I had also tried to run [www.xml-rpc.net](http://www.xml-rpc.net/)  with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)  on Windows XP and it worked in Mono .NET Runtime also properly. Just for information for everybody.